# What happens when `typeorm/browser/index.js` throws "Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' error"?

Tags: webpack, next.js, node-modules, typeorm, reflect-metadata

I recently came up with a new pure JS web app running on Node.js (not importing anything about TypeScript), having Next.js@12.0.10 as the framework and TypeORM@0.2.41 as the ORM layer to an Azure SQL server.

Everything works fine and I've connected to the SQL server successfully.

However, I accidentally deleted `package.json` without committing it. Anyway, I managed to re-install the missing packages, `typeorm`, `reflect-metadata` and `mssql`. But after the re-installation, when I started the dev server, I encountered a new error I've never seen before.

```
error - ./node_modules/typeorm/browser/index.js
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /*!
|  */
> import "reflect-metadata";
| // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| // Commonly Used exports
```

I've searched a bit and found it might be something related to webpack. But I have not much clue on this. The below is my `next.config.js` btw.

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.html$/i,
      loader: "html-loader",
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

I've tried some basic sanity checks like deleting the `node_modules/` and reinstalling but no luck. Does anyone have a clue on what's happening and how to fix it?

---

Update:

With the help of @hej and [this issue](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml/issues/208) on GitHub, I added this part to my `next.config.js` and it works!

```js
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      include: [/node_modules(.*[/\\])+typeorm/],
      type: "javascript/auto",
      use: "babel-loader",
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this to your webpack config:

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        include: [/node_modules(.*[/\\])+typeorm/],
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: This direction is very helpful and accurate. The only missing thing is `type: 'javascript/auto'` but it's almost there. Thanks!